# Get affected VCS roots inside build steps

Tags: teamcity

Can I determine VCS ROOTS (in multi vcs project configuration) which are affected by source changes at build-time for build duration optimization (skip build step for unchanged VCS ROOT)?

Comment: Having VCS Trigger means the build will be triggered just by VCS check-ins. Does it solve an initial problem of skipping build steps for unchanged VCS ROOT?

Comment: No. My build configuration uses 5 VCS ROOTS of 5 projects and 15 build steps to build all this depends projects. But when changes affects only 2 VCS ROOTS (for example), i may skip some build steps, but i must know this VCS ROOTS, that not changed.

Comment: Every build steps are performed for ~2 minutes. Even no changes sources.

Comment: This is very specific case I cannot help with. What I can recommend is to simplify the process. Having multiple repositories participated in single build process is strange. The point of having different repos is to have different builds, releases etc.